# trimming/splitting a string to get a street and number

Tags: .net, vb.net, split, .net-2.0, trim

I'm trying to figure out how i do this in the best way. i'm working in .NET 2.0 in VB.NET(this is not optional). here is my problem.

I got a string that contains a street and a number. lets say "Streetname 123"
I need from this a string "Streetname" and a string "123". that's simple enough for me to figure out myself. however there are other possible options. such as "123 Streetname", "Streetname A123", "Street name 123", "123A Street name",...

So i need to find something that works for each of these possible options.

Regards,

Bjorn

Comment: Do you also have apartment or numbers in streets? "3rd street 123 apt 4"

Comment: this is for in europe. i don't think that streets in europe have numbers. but i guess appartment numbers are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is probably going to be your most flexible option for this.  If you haven't learned about regular expressions yet, I'll warn you that there is a substantial learning curve to it, but I assure you that it's well worth the effort.  In this case, using regex will allow you to easily modify and expand the parsing rules in the future, as will almost certainly be necessary.  Here's an example of a method that uses regex to meet your stated specifications:

```
Public Function ParseAddress(input As String) As Address
    Dim streetNumberPattern As String = "(?<StreetNumber>[\d\w]+)"
    Dim streetNamePattern As String = "(?<StreetName>\D*?)"
    Dim pattern As String = $"^\s*({streetNamePattern}\s+{streetNumberPattern}|{streetNumberPattern}\s+{streetNamePattern})\s*$"
    Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
    Dim result As New Address()
    If m.Success Then
        result.StreetNumber = m.Groups("StreetNumber").Value
        result.StreetName = m.Groups("StreetName").Value
    End If
    Return result
End Function

Public Class Address
    Public Property StreetNumber As String
    Public Property StreetName As String
End Class
```

The complete regex pattern (the contents of the `pattern` variable), after it's concatenated together, is:

```
^\s*((?<StreetName>\D*?)\s+(?<StreetNumber>[\d\w]+)|(?<StreetNumber>[\d\w]+)\s+(?<StreetName>\D*?))\s*$
```

I just broke it up into multiple string literals to make it easier to read and maintain.

As you can see, it's quite powerful.  You can cram a lot of parsing rules into a very short pattern.  The pattern I provided won't handle every possible permutation, but it's a good start, and by using a regex pattern, it makes it easy to add to it in the future.

Comment: i'm getting allot of problems with this code. do know i need to work in vb.net 2.0. the regex stuff seems to be missing in this?

Comment: The `Regex` class has been part of the .NET Framework since version 1.1, so it's definitely available in 2.0  [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-2.0) is the documentation for the 2.0 version of it.  In .NET 2.0, it was declared by `System.dll`, so you must already have a reference to it.  So my guess is that you are just failing to import the namespace.  Try adding a `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` line to the top of your code file.